# How would we get to know the version code of the installed app in our device

Tags: android, adb

I have two .apk files with same version name but different version code and i installed one of the .apk file. is there any way to get to know which version of the .apk file is installed??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party file manager to see the version code of your apks.